# Python - Simple Scipy 'curve_fit' non linear regression with a basic log function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, non-linear-regression

I am relatively new to coding and have recently been asked by my research professor to create a log regression script to fit functions to experimental data. The input data is always small values (<10 for x,y) and contains no more than 5 data points per experiment.

I have managed to write a script using scipy's curve_fit function but the results I receive don't look correct? Would anyone be able to point out my errors in this simple script?

I have performed my own research on the use of the curve_fit function but it seems everyones case is very specific and any solution that I have found doesn't work with mine for some reason...

This is my code with a small bit of sample data;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import log as log

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * log(b * x) + c

x = np.array([0, 1.1029, 1.6148])
y = np.array([-8.5067, -6.8924, -6.713])

popt, pcov = curve_fit (func, x, y)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'k.', label = 'Raw Data')
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'k-', label = 'Fitted Curve')
plt.xlabel('ln(x)')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is the graph output that I get;

Graphical Output

[image]

Also note after line 12 is executed (the line with the curve_fit function), the following error appears;

```
RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800.
```

What does this error mean?

Also for a bonus question, does anyone know what the best way to potentially modify this into a multiple parameter regression would be? I understand if you add more variables you may be able to adjust the function in line 6,7 accordingly?

Thank you to whoever offers their expertise, it's much appreciated!

Comment: Not an answer, but a coding style suggestion:  Don't import `log` from the `scipy` namespace.  For "historical reasons", the `scipy` namespace includes most of the numpy functions, but it is recommended that you import numpy functions directly from numpy: `from numpy import log`.

Comment: Your array `x` includes 0, so it does not make sense to fit that data with the log function, since log(0) is -∞.

Comment: Final comment: your function has too many parameters, since `a*log(b*x) + c = a*(log(b)+log(x)) + c = a*log(x) + d`, where `d = a*log(b)+c`.  Use either `a*log(x) + c`, or `a*log(b*x)`.  (That's assuming you figure out how to deal with the 0 mentioned in my previous comment.)

Comment: Thanks Warren, seems I was too worried with the coding and disregarded the basic maths...

Comment: I've fixed the log formula and the log syntax as per your suggestion and it now fits a curve to the data! The curve is quite blocky however, ie. it is almost looks like a straight line was drawn between the points. Any ideas?

Comment: @JJ2244 In case you are really interessted in the function `y = a*log(x)+b` then don't bother with curve fit, the optimal values for `a` and `b` can be obtained analytically. This is a normal linear regression after you log transform the `x` coordinates.